# How to merge single band chunked raster tiles with ST_Union in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, merge

I have written the code below to select specific polygons and determine which grid tiles they intersect via a lookup table. Then depending on the grid tiles I want to merge the associated raster tiles from a single band chunked master raster file.

```
DROP TABLE dem_stats;
CREATE TABLE dem_stats AS
WITH
--  Select Features using lookup table and determine the raster tiles said features are intersecting
    feat AS 
        (SELECT title_no,
                grid_tile_name || '.asc' AS tile_name,
                wkb_geometry 
                FROM parcels_all_shapefile_building a, parcels_all_shapefile_lookup_osgb_grid_5km b
                    WHERE a.title_no = b.olp_title_no AND
                          a.title_no = 'AGL253216'
        ),
-- Merge rasters tiles from main raster file that intersect features        
    merged_rast AS
        (SELECT filename, ST_Union(rast,1) AS rast
            FROM dem, feat
                WHERE filename
                    IN (tile_name)
                        GROUP BY filename
        ),
-- As the tiles are now merged duplicates are not required
    feat_temp AS 
        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (title_no) * FROM feat
        ),
-- Clip merged raster and obtain pixel statistics
    b_stats AS
        (SELECT title_no, (stats).*
            FROM (SELECT title_no, ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(a.rast,1,b.wkb_geometry,-9999,true)) AS stats
                FROM merged_rast a
                    INNER JOIN feat_temp b
                ON ST_Intersects(b.wkb_geometry,a.rast)
            ) AS foo
        )
--  Summarise statistics for each title number
    SELECT title_no,
           count As pixel_val_count,
           min AS pixel_val_min,
           max AS pixel_val_max,
           mean AS pixel_val_mean,
           stddev AS pixel_val_stddev
            FROM b_stats
                WHERE count > 0;
```

Everything works except that instead of a single row result I am getting two as seen below:

[image]

So it looks like the raster tiles are not being merged correctly and the pixel statistics are being calculated for each raster tile. Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I shouldn't have been using GROUP BY, here is the replacement code for anyone wanting to do this in the future:

```
merged_rast AS
    (SELECT ST_Union(rast,1) AS rast
        FROM dem, feat
            WHERE filename
                IN (tile_name)*
```